# How to keyPress + click with selenium

Tags: selenium, click, key, keypress

I have a problem with my Selenium code not performing correctly the keyPress + click operation.

The test should open the jqueryui.com link and select the first 2 li elements on the page.

I am using Selenium 2.23 and Firefox 10. My code is as follows (I have trie 4 different ways to get it working but none performed):

> FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
>
> profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
>    WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
>    browser.get("http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/");
>
> List elements = browser.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol#selectable li"));
>
> ```
>  Actions a = new Actions(browser);      
>  a.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
>  .moveToElement(elements.get(0))
>  .click()
>  .moveToElement(elements.get(1))
>  .click()
>  .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
>  .build()
>  .perform();
>
>     Keyboard keyboard = ((HasInputDevices) browser).getKeyboard();
>     keyboard.pressKey(Keys.CONTROL);
>     List<WebElement> selectOptions = browser.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol#selectable li"));
>     selectOptions.get(1).click();
>     selectOptions.get(3).click();
>     keyboard.releaseKey(Keys.CONTROL);
> ```

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(browser);
    builder.keyDown(elements.get(0), Keys.CONTROL)
        .click(elements.get(0))
        .click(elements.get(1))
        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
    Action selectMultiple = builder.build();
    selectMultiple.perform();

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK);
    elements.get(0).click();
    elements.get(1).click();
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK);

    browser.quit();
```

Can anyone help me with some other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really have no idea why none of your attempts work (particularly the first one). The key constants are a mess.

Anyway, I have been able to make this work (on Windows XP):

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
elements.get(0).click();
elements.get(1).click();
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bug in Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3734&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary), affecting shift/control/alt combined with clicks on Firefox for Windows.  Star the bug and perhaps they will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that`s not a bug.

Try use this (C#):

```
Action builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.KeyDown(Keys.Control);
builder.Click(element1);
builder.Click(element2);
builder.KeyUp(Keys.Control);
builder.Perform();
```

or for you(Java):

> Actions a = new Actions(browser);        a.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL) 
>   .moveToElement(elements.get(0))  .click() 
>   .moveToElement(elements.get(1))  .click()  .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL) 
>   .build()  .perform();

Just instead of

> .Click();   .build();   .perform();

use

```
a.Click(YourWebElement);
a.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
a.build();
a.perform();
```

Should works,